# java -version looking at wrong location and not showing correct java version macOS

Tags: java, macos, terminal, java-15

I guess I have messed up big time with my java installation and am now not able to correct this.

Ok, so first, `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` tells me

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    15, x86_64: "Java SE 15"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Secondly, Java home is set up properly.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But when I do, java -version, it says

```
java -version
-bash: /opt/anaconda3/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Don't know why it is going to /opt/anaconda3/ directory.

Another thing, I read that `/usr/bin/java` points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`

and if I want to use the new java version, I need to replace the `/usr/bin/java` symlink so that it points to `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` instead using,

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin
```

But, apparently I cannot remove the symlink
`rm: /usr/bin/java: Operation not permitted`

What should be the approach now?

Comment: Does explicitly saying `/usr/bin/java -version` work?

Comment: Yes, this does work.
`java version "15" 2020-09-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: Then I think it's a problem with your `$PATH`. What does `echo $PATH` say? Does it have `/opt/anaconda3/bin` before `/usr/bin`? If so, try putting `/opt/anaconda3/bin` after `/usr/bin`, so that the latter is prioritised.